# XmlSerializer.Deserialize method appends timezone to a time and datetime field

Tags: web-services, datetime, formatting, timezone, xmlserializer

Have a small script in Microsoft.NET 2.0 that deserializes a XML back to a typed object, connects dyanimcally to a web service using ServiceDescription and binds the deserialized typed object to the WebMethod inbound. The XML prior to serialization looks like below

```
<completion_time>12:19:38</completion_time>
```

on the wire when communicating to the web service looks like below

```
<completion_time>12:19:38.0000000-04:00</completion_time>
```

with the timezone appended to the end. This is causing the time to be read differently when communicating to a web service at a different timezone. is there anyway to let XmlSerializer skip the timezone? Or any other known workarounds?

Comment: Mark your ansers as correct and I think ppl will help you!

Comment: Ppl are helpful, thanks for stoping by and you can get your panties untwisted now

Comment: so.... which is the answer, then?

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same issue. Finally found the [DateTimeMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.datetimemode.aspx) property on the DataColumn object. It takes a member of the [DataSetDateTime enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datasetdatetime.aspx) which controls how the Time is serialized. Setting it to Unspecified will prevent the serializer from doing any conversion of the time.

You can loop through an existing DataSet and set the mode like the following:

```
        foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns) {
            if (column.DataType == typeof(DateTime)) {
                column.DateTimeMode = DataSetDateTime.Unspecified;
            }   
        }
```

Comment: This saved my bacon, thanks.I had changed the kind to DateTimeKind.Unspecified of the item in the datarow, but this seems to be overridden by the DateTimeMode setting. If DateTimeMode is set to unspecified then it ignores the kind of the item in the data row.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the type of 'completion_time' field from DateTime to string and use datetime formater to get datetime string without timezone

DateTime date = DateTime.UtcNow;
date.ToString("hh:mm:ss");

Answer (score 0):

http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2004/04/13/112784.aspx

```
[XmlElementAttribute(DataType="date")]

public DateTime date;
```

or

```
[XmlAttributeAttribute(DataType="date")]

public DateTime date;
```

Comment: Thanks eschneider, but the links says this solution doesn't work for SOAP Serializer.